# R + match values at scale (using apply?)

Tags: r, match, mapply

Is there a way to make matching values at scale more programmatic? Basically what I want to do is add a bunch of columns for value lookups onto a dataframe, but I don't want to write the match[] argument every time. It seems like this would be a use case for *mapply* but I can't quite figure out how to use it here. Any suggestions?

Here's the data:

```
data <- data.frame(
    region = sample(c("northeast","midwest","west"), 50, replace = T),
    climate = sample(c("dry","cold","arid"), 50, replace = T),
    industry = sample(c("tech","energy","manuf"), 50, replace = T))
```

And the corresponding lookup tables:

```
lookups <- data.frame(
    orig_val = c("northeast","midwest","west","dry","cold","arid","tech","energy","manuf"),
    look_val = c("dir1","dir2","dir3","temp1","temp2","temp3","job1","job2","job3")
    )
```

So now what I want to do is: First add a column to "data" that's called "reg_lookups" and it will match the region to its appropriate value in "lookups". Do the same for "climate_lookups" and so on.

Right now, I've got this mess:

```
data$reg_lookup <- lookups$look_val[match(data$region, lookups$orig_val)]
data$clim_lookup <- lookups$look_val[match(data$climate, lookups$orig_val)]
data$indus_lookup <- lookups$look_val[match(data$industry, lookups$orig_val)]
```

I've tried using a function to do this, but the function doesn't seem to work, so then applying that to *mapply* is a no-go (plus I'm confused about how the mapply syntax would work here):

```
match_fun <- function(df, newval, df_look, lookup_val, var, ref_val) {
    df$newval <- df_look$lookup_val[match(df$var, df_look$ref_val)]
    return(df)
}

data2 <- match_fun(data, reg_2, lookups, look_val, region, orig_val)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `merge`?

Comment: or just reformatting the existing columns?

Comment: @joran, not using merge mainly because I want separate columns for the different factors, so I want one column for the "dir" 1-3 matches, another column for the "temp" 1-3 matches, and another column for the "job" 1-3 matches. Is there a way to get that through merge?

Comment: @rawr, how do you suggest reformatting the existing columns? I'd like to keep the original data, but I could just as easily copy the columns and reformat the copies; just not sure what you mean, exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just trying to do this:

```
data <- merge(data,lookups[1:3,],by.x = "region",by.y = "orig_val",all.x = TRUE)
data <- merge(data,lookups[4:6,],by.x = "climate",by.y = "orig_val",all.x = TRUE)
data <- merge(data,lookups[7:9,],by.x = "industry",by.y = "orig_val",all.x = TRUE)
```

But it would be much better to store the lookups either in separate data frames. That way you can control the names of the new columns more easily. It would also allow you to do something like this:

```
lookups1 <- split(lookups,rep(1:3,each = 3))
colnames(lookups1[[1]]) <- c('region','reg_lookup')
colnames(lookups1[[2]]) <- c('climate','clim_lookup')
colnames(lookups1[[3]]) <- c('industry','indus_lookup')

do.call(cbind,mapply(merge,
        x = list(data[,1,drop = FALSE],data[,2,drop =FALSE],data[,3,drop = FALSE]),
        y = lookups1,
        moreArgs = list(all.x = TRUE),
        SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
```

and you should be able to wrap that `do.call` bit in a function.

I used `data[,1,drop = FALSE]` in order to preserve them as one column data frames.

The way you structure `mapply` calls is to pass named arguments as lists (the `x =` and `y =` parts). I wanted to be sure to preserve all the rows from `data`, so I passed `all.x = TRUE` via `moreArgs`, so that gets passed each time `merge` is called. Finally, I need to stitch them all together myself, so I turned off `SIMPLIFY`.

Comment: Hm, so that could work, but from a code perspective, that doesn't look much more efficient than calling "match" for each individual instance. What I'm curious about is if there's a way to do this in one call?

Comment: This is it! But I'm a bit confused by some parts of the syntax. 1) why use "drop=FALSE" in the x= part, rather than x = list(data$region, data$climate, data$industry)? 2) would you mind giving a quick explanation of what is happening in the mapply portion of the code?